# Windows Task Scheduler batch file fails to xcopy file to mapped network share

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, xcopy

I have a batch file which creates backup of SQL DB, makes a zip file and then copies to a mapped network share.

When this batch file is executed from command prompt or RUN window it works perfectly fine. However, when the batch file is called by Windows Task Scheduler it fails to copy file to mapped network share with the error #4.

The run account used in Task Scheduler is same as I am using for Command Prompt. Both the machines are on workgroup with the same user name and password, so sharing permission does not seem to be an issue.

The code is:

```
set ZipFileName=C:\Temp\ST_%date:~10%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%.zip
C:\Windows\System32\xcopy %ZipFileName% "Z:\WinDB\" /Z /V
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 GOTO error_hndlr
------
:error_hndlr
echo Failed with error #%errorlevel%
exit /B
```

Comment: have you tried with checking the box "Run with highest privileges"?

Comment: Yes, I did it but the error is as it was

Comment: In your normal account, right click on the scheduled task and run it.  As Task scheduler defaults to the system account `which has no network permissions`, this should prove that it works when network permissions are given.

Comment: Try adding a net use command to map it during the script or go-fer \\UNC\path instead.

Comment: I did use the administrator accounts to run the task the error is same. So I ended up using 'net use' command to map the drive and it works fine. The only caveat is the password which is in plain text.